# How to structure data without bloating the size because of alignment?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-alignment

Lets say we have a struct `Original` as this:

```
class Original
{
  int x;
  bool y;
  bool z;
};
```

Due to alignment, the `sizeof(Original)` is 8 bytes. 4 for the int, 2 for the bools, and 2 alignment "hole".

But when i decide, that I want to structure my code, and for some reason, `x` and `y` should go together, I might want to refactor this structure into this:

```
class A
{
  int x;
  bool y;
};

class Original
{
  A a;
  bool y;
};
```

The Original class contains still the same stuff, but suddenly its `sizeof(Original)` went from 8 bytes to 12 bytes, because `sizeof(A)` is 8 bytes (4 + 1, aligned to 8), and (8 + 1) is aligned again to 12.

Since this is hardly and rarely acceptable, as we are throwing away memory space and performance, this leads us to have big and ugly structures whenever performance is relevant.

I thought that alignas might solve it, but `aligignas(1)` on the A didn't change anything.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Use #pragma pack

Comment: Do you have benchmarking to the effect that your memory use is excessive and causing performance penalties, or do you just have a feeling that 12 bytes for this struct is more than it "ought" to be?

Comment: @nathan With todays hardware with caching etc. Programs (that I happen to write and optimise) tend to be strictly memory bound, and other aspects don't really matter that much (if usage for example).
I have repeated experience that adding/removing few bytes from structs is almost guaranteed to have performance effect.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but with inheritance (e.g.: `class Original : public A`) compilers have a better chance of packing the members together (not entirely sure if that is guaranteed by the standard)

Comment: @Adrian Pragma seems to be little bit "strong" weapon for this, as it removes any padding inside the structure. A is super simple in this example, but it could contain a lot of fields with different sizes, and I might not want to pack the individual fields. I basically just want to make sure, that the "hole" at the end of A isn't applied when A is directly in other struct.

Comment: If there is one structure stored in your program, then the compiler actually does a good job (alignment is often good for performance except when it is too big). If there are many of them, then it is suboptimal. But the thing is that the compiler is restricted by the C++ standard and the ABI on the target platform (typically Itanium). You can tell compilers to pack structure but this is non-standard. If you plan to put such structure in an array, then the layout will certainly not be optimal, even if packed. Can you tell us more about the use-case?

Comment: `alignas` is used to increase the alignment requirement, not reduce it. For example to align an array of `char` to 32 for SIMD purpose

Comment: @JérômeRichard Lets assume, that my reasons for trying to keep the size small are legitimate. Implying that I probably don't really need that, is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @kovarex My main point was just that the best layout is dependent of the context/use-case. For example, AoS are known to be inefficient (both in time and space). This is why I asked for more information.

Comment: Never use #pragma pack for anything you read or write more than once. It forces the compiler to access the data byte by byte on any architecture which requires aligned access.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot avoid padding of the class to satisfy the alignment of `int` (within limits of the C++ standard).

You can potentially avoid the extra padding from alignment of intermediate sub object by making it a "potentially overlapping subobject". Being a potentially overlapping sub object allows the padding to be reused for other sub objects.

This can be achieved for by either making it a base sub object instead of a data member, or by using the `no_­unique_­address` attribute.

```
struct Original : A
{
    bool z;
};

struct Original
{
    [[no_­unique_­address]] A a;
    bool z;
};
```

However, it's still up to the language implementation whether it will overlap the potentially overlapping sub objects. For example, the Itanium ABI will only do so if the sub object type is "non-POD" as defined by the ABI. This can be achieved for example by using non-public access specifiers (members in your example are private, so this is satisfied), or by declaring a constructor:

```
struct A
{
protected:
    int x;
    bool y;
};

struct A
{
    int x;
    bool y;

    A(const A&) = default;
};
```

Comment: GCC and Clang actually reduce the size of the structure with `[[no_unique_address]]` but not MSVC yet. See: https://godbolt.org/z/ezen95P7W .

Comment: @JérômeRichard "Not yet" is a challenging proposition, since changing it would break the ABI. Your example demonstrates, that only using non-public members is sufficient for Itanium ABI to overlap the sub objects. It doesn't happen when all members are public.

Comment: @JérômeRichard you can temporarily use [`[[msvc::no_unique_address]]`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/) instead https://godbolt.org/z/qhPMvW7Pn

Comment: @phuclv What is the benefit of using this (non-standard?) attribute since it does not change the result compared to `[[no_unique_address]]` which is portable (ie. the size is left unchanged)?

Comment: @JérômeRichard MS already explained the reason for not supporting `no_unique_address` at the moment in the previous link. But yes the `[[msvc::no_unique_address]]` result is a bug, I didn't check the output earlier

Answer (score 0):

If you use inheritance the compiler can place the added member variables in the padding:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  int x;
  bool y;
};

class Original : public A
{
  bool z;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(Original) << std::endl;
}
```

Output: 8

Note: if you make all members and inheritance public then Original will even be an aggregate type.

Comment: still not work for MSVC https://godbolt.org/z/s4zavrjr9

Comment: Urgs, now try to link .o files from gcc and msvc together.